# Why array not turned out to be null?

Tags: c#, arrays, arr

I'm bit confused on this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    int[] p=new int[4];
    p[0] = 25;
    method(p);
    string o = p[0].ToString();
}
private void method(int[] k)
{
    k[0] = 34;
    k = null; //##
}
```

Scene 1 : If i remove `k=null`, then my `p[0]` turns out as `34` which was modified in 'method' function. Array is reference type so nothing to wonder.

Scene 2 : with `k=null`, still my `p[0]` returns `34` instead of `null`. Why it is so? here i'm making entire array as null but how still first element carries `34`?

Comment: You are *not* passing by reference. That requires the `ref` keyword. If you use the assignment operator (=), it will not affect the variable in the calling scope unless you pass by reference. However, if you change *properties* and *state* of a regular parameter, that *does* change the variable in the calling scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what you do is passing the reference of the array to the `method` and it creates a `new` reference `int[] k` that refers to the same item as your caller's variable `p` does, **but it is not** `p`.

what becomes `null` is the `new` `int[] k` in the `method`, not the variable `p` from the caller.

```
int i = 1;
int[] p=new int[4]; //p is here
p[0] = 25;
method(p);
string o = p[0].ToString();

//this is k, it is a new int[] reffering to the same item as p, but not p
private void method(int[] k) 
{
    k[0] = 34;
    k = null; //##
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making the reference to the array null, you are not making the array null. If you change your argument to be `ref int[] k` and call it as `method(ref p)`, then it would behave as you are expecting.

For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    int[] p=new int[4];
    p[0] = 25;
    method(ref p);
    string o = p[0].ToString();
}
private void method(ref int[] k)
{
    k[0] = 34;
    k = null; //##
}
```

Comment: thanks @rob unfortunately i am able to mark one answer as correct.